# How to query a dynamic 2D- array with only one pointer using new in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic, 2d

i read about 2D-Arrays and how to allocate and get the values on stackoverflow. So the proposition is to allocate only a block of memory like this:

```
int *ary = new int[sizeX*sizeY];
```

and to acces it like this:

```
ary[i*sizeX+j]
```

but let's assume sizeX is 2 and sizeY is 3, so we will get for position i = 0 & j = 2 and i = 1 & j = 0 the same value, for each of them the value 2 because 0*2+2 = 2 and 1*2+0=2, so we see call the same variable in the array, but we want a different position. Am i missing something or are there suggestions of how make it right?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should multiply `i` by the size of the second dimension, so if `sizeX` is 2 then `j = 2` doesn't exist. Assuming X is your first dimension and Y is your second dimension, you'll want to do `i * sizeY + j`.